# WINDOWS 2k8R2: Remove (or to do something else) on older files in the directory based on their names

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, string-matching

I can produce directory names based on current date/time: getting these values from WMIC into environment variables to produce:

```
set BackDirName="%year%%month%%day%"
mkdir %BackDirName%
```

After running the batch for several times, I got a number of directories like:

```
20140901
20140908
...
20141127
```

And I want to keep only some newest directories, removing older ones. Here's how it may look in some abstract pseudo-PL:

```
rem in this PL array's items numbered starting from 1
declare var_dir_list:array of string
:start
rem listing all like 20YYMM* - I'll die before year 2100 :-)
list_dirs 20[1-9][0-9][0-1][0-9]* order:alphabetic direction:a-to-z  
    names_per_line:1 show:only-names =>var_dir_list
if number_of_lines(var_dir_list) GT 4 then
    rem deleting first directory in list
    remove_dir name:var_dir_list[1]
    rem removing first line from list
    var_dir_list=var_dir_list[2..number_of_lines(var_dir_list)]
    goto start
end if
```

The pseudo-code above iterates and deletes all but last (newest) 4 directories. I need to emulate this functionality using built-in Windows' batch file processors. But the lack of proper documentation *(OMFG! Why MS did not ship the off-line help with 2008, like it did with 2003?)* makes me mad.
I can't rely on creation/modification dates of these folders/files, that's why I hardcoded the date in their names.

And I have no idea how to implement such functionality, if it is possible at all. Any practical suggestions please? (using VBscript is acceptable)

Thank you.

Comment: You should also have powershell on Windows2k8R2. Probably a lot easier than batch.

Comment: @Blorgbeard and how much documentation on PS is shipped with 2008r2? Is it enough to work at internet-less location?

Comment: No idea, just something to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code gets a list of all directories in the source directory (you'll have to specify this), sorts them by date in reverse order, skips the first four, and deletes the rest.

```
@echo off
set source_dir="C:\Where\The\Directories\Are"

:: Takes a list of all directories in the source directory
:: /a:d grabs only directories
:: /:o-d sorts them in reverse by date (newest on top)
:: /b gets simple filenames so that this actually works
:: "skip=4" skips the first four listed
:: rd /s deletes recursively
:: /q forces the deletion without asking
:: and the rest are deleted
for /f "skip=4 tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:d /o:-d /b %source_dir%') do rd /s /q %source_dir%\%%A
```

Comment: I got your idea and implemented it before you've answered. But thanks for your answer and for optimizations.
But I can't agree with your edits of my question: IRL the Bash shell and numerous command-line utilities allows to solve this task easier. I missing "man" and (especially!) "apropos" commands in windows. "command /?" isn't the same because of lack of "pager", allowing to search etc...

Comment: I was mostly getting rid of the "don't ask why I need this; I just do" bit. Nobody cares WHY you need it, and it's obvious that you needed it or else you wouldn't have posted here.

Comment: Don't blame me. I've seen too much forums where asking ones got "answers" like "why should anyone need that at all?"  

Typical situation:  
Q: - Hey, guys! I want to hammer the nails with microscope. Suggest me most suitable model please?  
A1: - No one will use microscope as a hammer! You should not do that.  
A2: - Use the clay brick, as my grandpa always did  
etc etc...  
Results: ton of answers like A1 & A2, and no one really answered the question asked. OK, may be SE is better community, where people answering the questions, as it required by local code of behavior.

Comment: As to be more on-topic. One thing in your answer I'll strongly disagree: the sorting order "o-d". Windows can not copy directories preserving their timestamps, and should the directory be copied to another location, it will get new creation/modification timestamp. I can't rely on it, that's why I using dates YYYYMMDD in directory names.

Answer (score 0):

That is the solution I implemented filnally.
It may be not very optimal, but it works and allows customizations.
Optimizations are appreciated.

At first, I need the date and the time regardless of current locale. Then I made two separate files to get the values I need. I could write their code as "subroutines" inside the main file, but these pieces of code are reusable and I prefer to have them as "external libraries".

GetDateTime.bat

```
rem GetDateTime.bat
rem Reading date and time into environment variables
rem This file should be CALLed from other .bats
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get day /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get month /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get year /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get hour /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get minute /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
rem echo -%dayofweek%-
rem echo %year%-%month%-%day% %hour%:%minute%
```

normalizeDT.bat

```
rem normalizeDT.bat
rem Normalize some values, adding leading zeros if needed
if /i %month% lss 10 (
set mon1=0%month%
) else (
set mon1=%month%
)
if /i %day% lss 10 (
set day1=0%day%
) else (
set day1=%day%
)
if /i %hour% lss 10 (
set hou1=0%hour%
) else (
set hou1=%hour%
)
if /i %minute% lss 10 (
set min1=0%minute%
) else (
set min1=%minute%
)
set month=%mon1%
set day=%day1%
set minute=%min1%
set hour=%hou1%
```

Then the main file. It may be launched at every time, but creates new backup only on Mondays.

weeklyFullBackup.bat

```
@echo off
@rem weeklyFullBackup.bat
@rem creating full/incremental backup

setlocal

@rem Base directory for creating subdirectories for backups
set BackUpBaseDir=d:\usrback

@rem The prefix for name of backup subdirectories
set BackDirNamePrefix=WBK

@rem How many old backups to store
set MaxBackNumber=4

@rem The directory to be backed up
set BackUpThis=c:\share

@rem Directory for storing RoboCopy logs
set RCLogDir=d:\var\log

@rem Reading date, time and the day of week (latter not used now, but may be used later)
@call getdatetime
@call normalizeDT

@rem Temporary files name - may differ from the name of backup directory!
set tempDT=%year%%month%%day%%hour%%minute%

@rem Resetting the flags, they can be set during ARGS parsing
set DoForce=
set DoNotPurge=
set ParametersAreCorrect=

@rem Parsing possible command line parameter
@rem Several ECHOS like "not forced" are for debugging purposes
if "%1"=="" (
echo No parameters. Behaving default.
set ParametersAreCorrect=YES
)
if "%1"=="/f" (
set DoForce=YES
set ParametersAreCorrect=YES
echo Forcing new backup
) else (
echo Not forced by /f
)
if "%1"=="/n" (
set DoNotPurge=YES
set ParametersAreCorrect=YES
echo Forcing NOT to purge old backups
) else (
echo Not forced by /n
)
if "%1"=="/fn" (
echo Forcing new backup
echo Forcing NOT to purge old backups
set DoForce=YES
set DoNotPurge=YES
set ParametersAreCorrect=YES
) else (
echo Not forced by /fn
)

if "%1"=="/?" (
:HelpAndExit
echo "%0 [/f|/n|/fn]"
echo /f - Force creation of new backup even if today is not Monday
echo /n - Not erase old backups
echo /fn - force and not erase
goto :eof
)

@rem ParametersAreCorrect become non-empy on acceptable parameter detection
@rem If the parameter is non-acceptable, we'll show the help and then quit
@rem It's weird to jump to a label inside compound operator, but it works.
if "%ParametersAreCorrect%"=="" (
echo Wrong parameters!
echo.
goto HelpAndExit
)

:WorkingNow

@rem Forcing creation of new backup if thoday is Monday
if "%DayOfWeek%"=="1" (
set DoForce=YES
echo Monday - Forcing new backup
)
@rem on Monday creating new subdirectory for new backup, on other day of week using last existing one
@rem If there was parameter /f or /fn, we pretend that today is Monday and forcing new backup
if "%DoForce%"=="YES" goto ItIsMonday

echo Not Monday, neither we forced to work, so will not create new backup subdir
@rem ==================================
@rem lookig for last backup subdirectory and using it
@rem sorting subdirs from oldest to newest to skip all but last one
dir /ad /b /on %BackupBaseDir%\%BackDirNamePrefix%*>"%tempDT%.tmp"
@rem FINDing the ":LPT:" string - it can't appear in file/directory name
type "%tempDT%.tmp"|find /c /v ":LPT:">"%tempDT%n.tmp"
@rem Setting environment variable from file
set /p NumOfDirs=<"%tempDT%n.tmp"
@rem Skipping all lines but last one
set /a NumOfDirs-=1
for /f "usebackq skip=%NumOfDirs%" %%I in (`type "%tempDT%.tmp"`) do (
echo Using [%%I]
set BackDirName=%%I
)
@rem ==================================

@rem we don't need to create new backup directory, then skipping the creation code
goto SkipMKDIR

:ItIsMonday

set BackDirName=%BackDirNamePrefix%%year%%month%%day%
if "%DayOfWeek%"=="1" (
echo "Today (%year%-%month%-%day%) is Monday"
) else (
echo "Today (%year%-%month%-%day%) is NOT Monday, but new backup is forced"
)
echo creating [%BackDirName%]
@rem On Mondays checking the existence of subdirectory - just for case
if exist "%BackupBaseDir%\%BackDirName%" (
echo dir is already exists [%BackupBaseDir%\%BackDirName%]
goto SkipMKDIR
)
echo dir is not exists [%BackupBaseDir%\%BackDirName%]

@rem To catch possible errors during MKDIR we turning off the extended commands handling:
@rem I will not create the entire path: if BaseDir not exists, then something is wrong
cmd /e:off /c mkdir %BackupBaseDir%\%BackDirName%
if errorlevel 1 (
echo Can't create dir [%BackupBaseDir%\%BackDirName%]
echo Aborting!
exit
)
:SkipMKDIR

@rem The backup itself
robocopy %BackUpThis% %BackupBaseDir%\%BackDirName% /copy:DATO /xf "~*.*" *.tmp *.wbk thumbs.db /xd ".recycle" /e /r:1 /w:5 /unilog:"%RCLogDir%\%TempDT%.RC.log" /dcopy:t /mt
set RoboErr=%errorlevel%
echo RoboCopy returned [%RoboErr%]
@rem RoboCopy's return codes taken here:
@rem http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
if /i %RoboErr% geq 8 (
echo Something wrong with this backup. NOT removing old backups, regardless of forsage state
echo Do not removing temporary files %TempDT%*.*
echo Consult log file [%RCLogDir%\%TempDT%.RC.log]
goto :eof
)
rem On successful new backup we may remove older ones.

if "%DoNotPurge%"=="YES" (
echo Forced to NOT remove old backups, skipping removal
goto SkipOldRemoval
)

@rem Very similar to above: getting list of existing backup directories and
@rem removing all but given number of them
dir /ad /b /o-n %BackupBaseDir%\%BackDirNamePrefix%*>"%tempDT%.tmp"
type "%tempDT%.tmp"|find /c /v ":LPT:">"%tempDT%n.tmp"
set /p NumOfDirs=<"%tempDT%n.tmp"

if /i %NumOfDirs% leq %MaxBackNumber% (
@rem Do nothing if there's not enough old backups
echo NOT removing old backups: %NumOfDirs% Less than %MaxBackNumber%.
goto SkipOldRemoval
)
@rem There's enough old backups, we should delete some
echo REMOVING old backups!: %NumOfDirs% Greater than %MaxBackNumber%

for /f "usebackq skip=%MaxBackNumber%" %%I in (`type "%tempDT%.tmp"`) do (
echo Removing [%%I]
rmdir /s /q %BackupBaseDir%\%%I
)

:SkipOldRemoval

@rem House cleaning
del "%tempDT%*.tmp"
endlocal
```